# Can someone help me with this math question?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

The fibboican sequence $a_1, a_2, ...$ is defined by $a_1=a_2=1$, and for integers $k \ge 3$,

$$ \begin{cases} a_k=a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}, & \text{if $k$ is odd,} \\
\dfrac{1}{a_k}=\dfrac{1}{a_{k-1}}+\dfrac{1}{a_{k-2}}, & \text{if $k$ is even.}
\end{cases}$$

Prove that, for each integer $m \ge 1$, the numerator of $a_m$ (when written in simplest form) is a power of $2$.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried plugging things in and idk what to do now

Comment: Are you familiar with induction ?

Comment: I have heard of that but never tried to use it, can someone post a solution so I can understand?

Comment: @coffeemath But I found $a_8=16/35$ and $a_9=128/35$.

Comment: @YanPeng I see. I'll delete my comment and try again.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my hints, maybe can help you to understand:

At first, you can prove that $a_{2n-1}=(2n-1)a_{2n}$ holds for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$. You can prove it by using induction:

- At first, the equality holds when $n=1$;
- Please suppose the equality holds when $n=k$, which means $a_{2k-1}=(2k-1)a_{2k}$. Then, you can try to prove that $a_{2k+1}=(2k+1)a_{2k+2}$ by using the hypothesis. It is easy because
  $$ a_{2k+1} = a_{2k}+a_{2k-1} = a_{2k}+(2k-1)a_{2k} = 2k a_{2k}, $$
  $$ \dfrac{1}{a_{2k+2}} = \dfrac{1}{a_{2k+1}}+\dfrac{1}{a_{2k}} = (\dfrac{1}{2k}+1)\dfrac{1}{a_{2k}} = \dfrac{2k+1}{2k a_{2k}}. $$
  (please finish it by yourself.)

Then, it can be easily derived that
$$ \dfrac{a_{2k}}{a_{2k+2}} = \dfrac{2k+1}{2k}, \quad \forall k\in\mathbb{Z}_+, $$
we have
$$ \begin{aligned}
a_{2n} &= a_2\dfrac{a_4}{a_2}\dfrac{a_6}{a_4}\cdots\dfrac{a_{2n}}{a_{2n-2}} \\ 
&= 1\cdot\dfrac{2}{3}\cdot\dfrac{4}{5}\cdot\cdots\cdot\dfrac{2n-2}{2n-1} \\
&= \dfrac{\big(2\cdot 4\cdots\cdot(2n-2)\big)^2}{(2n-1)!} \\
&= \dfrac{2^{2n-2}\big((n-1)!\big)^2}{(2n-1)!} \\
&= 2^{2n-2}\Big/\left(n\cdot {2n-1 \choose n}\right),
\end{aligned} $$
and then
$$ a_1 = 1, \quad a_{2n+1} = 2^{2n}\Big/{2n \choose n} $$
follows.

Comment: uhhh... I don't really get it, is there an easier proof?

Comment: @Hello_People I advise you first to say thank you to Yan Peng, then say him/her where you don't understand. And an advise: try to work a little **by yourself**.